# Apache 2.2 won't start with an ipv6 address

Tags: apache-2.2, ipv6, localhost

I'm trying to only allow the localhost on a certain folder, it works perfect with ipv4 (`Allow from 127.0.0.1`) but as soon as I add ipv6 (`Allow from [::1]`) my Apache won't start anymore.

I checked the `error.log` and it says:

The specified IP address is invalid.

I already typed the ipv6 address without the compressed format, didn't work either.

I'm using Apache 2.2.25, Windows 8.1. IPv6 is enabled on my computer.

Comment: Which OS (and Linux distribution), is Apache compiled from source or installed with a package manager, does your machine have ipv6 fully configured, etc.  Unless you add more detail, I suspect this question will be at risk of being closed.

Answer (score 2):

The notation where you surround the IPv6 address with brackets is only used in cases where there might be confusion between the address and an optional port number.

One example is in the [`Listen`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) directive. Because it can specify both an address and a port the brackets have to be added to avoid confusion: `Listen 2001:db8::1:8080` is invalid because it could both mean `Listen [2001:db8::1]:8080` and `Listen [2001:db8::1:8080]`. The brackets make it explicit.

For the [`Allow from`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow) directive this is not the case. When specifying an address it is always an address without a port number. Therefore `Allow from 2001:db8::1:8080` is never ambiguous. It is always IPv6 address `2001:db8::1:8080`.

If you leave out the brackets (`Allow from ::1`) it should work.

Comment: Hmm I didn't know that about the brackets. But I tried it again and it still won't work. let me just give you the code i'm trying to get to work <Directory "something">
  Options FollowSymLinks Includes
  DirectoryIndex index.html
  
  AllowOverride None
  Order Deny,Allow
  
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
  Allow from ::1
</Directory>

Answer (score 0):

Your virtualhost hev to be defined like this `<VirtualHost *:80>`which is allowing access for both ipv4 and ipv6.

Also, Apache documentation uses this format for ipv6 restriction :
`Allow from 2001:db8::a00:20ff:fea7:ccea`
[Apache doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_authz_host.html)